# insert list into one row in python3 sqlite3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sqlite

So suppose I made an sqlite3 database in which I made a table

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE tablnam(thing TEXT, thing2 TEXT, thing3 TEXT)")
```

then I made a list

`list = ["a","b","c"]`

How would I go about inserting that one list into tablnam in just one row. 
I've tried

`c.execute("insert into this values(?)",list)`

but it returns
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type`

so to clarify for those who don't understand: I want to insert a lists values, into ONE row in an sqlite3 table in python
thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well buddy, that can't work, you are trying to put a **list** where a **text** belongs. Try doing it that way:

`c.execute("INSERT INTO tablenam(thing, thing2, thing3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",list[0], list[1], list[2])`

Differences to your suggestions:

- I am putting a single **string** into each **text** field
- you can only insert **exactly three** list items per row.
- I've changed your SQL Syntax to contain `tablenam` and also put in the column names
- changed the SQL style: keywords in allcaps

Note that you **can't** (and shouldn't) put an **entire list** into a **single row** in a DB. If you have to do something along those lines, have a look at foreign keys.